# Enter UV coordinates position

Tags: uv, transforms, uv-image-editor

How can I manually type in the coordinates for my UVs?

Currently I am seeing these buttons:

[image]

But these simply adjust according to mouse movements.

The reason for this is my model is simply 2 quads with their UVs overlaid. I would like to snap these UVs is certain tiles on my texture map - much like a tile map.

Perhaps there is a better way to do this than manually entering the coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UV editor press N to display the Information panel on the right.  At the top is the UV Vertex section where you can type the values directly.

[image]

Based on what you've said, it might also be useful to enable "Snap to Pixels" in the UVs menu.